# SSL Termination with Nginx for all HTTP Methods

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, https

I am trying to implement SSL Termination using Nginx. I need to force all traffic over https, so I have this rule in my Nginx configuration:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This works great for the browser, and also when I hit the api directly with https. However, if I hit the api over http with requests using other HTTP methods(POST, PUT, etc), it treats them as GET methods instead. I understand this is happening because of the 301 being returned, but how can I still keep this forced-SSL behavior to occur for all HTTP Methods?

Comment: For API, a redirect is discouraged because only hide the problem! You should answer an error on the http entries of the API to avoid security holes.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Turns out HTTP code 307 behaves the exact same as a 303, but doesn't require changing the HTTP method. Returning that code instead solves the problem:

```
return 307 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```